# git - git status slow on remote machine after executing git status on local machine which mounts remote using sshfs

Tags: git, ssh, centos, sshfs

I have a local machine(Centos 7) that mounts a repo from remote machine(Centos 6) using sshfs(2.10). And I can connect them both using ssh in my laptop. My daily workflow is opening my laptop, ssh to the local machine, and work on the mounted repo from the remote machine.

Before mounting, executing `git status` directly on the remote repo was fast. But after I mounting the remote and executing `git status` on the local machine, executing `git status` directly on the remote repo again became slow!

I know that executing `git status` in the local machine can be slow because of sshfs. But I believe that git commands should always be fast on the remote. So now I want to figure out the reason.

Firstly, I tried to disable caching of sshfs in the local machine with the command like `sshfs -o cache=no -o cache_timeout user@ip:/path/to/repo path/to/repo`, but the situation was not changed.

After that I tried to close the local machine, ssh to the remote directly and work for a while(about 5 minutes), then I was surprised to find that executing `git status` became fast again.

So I guess there exists some communication of sshfs between local machine and remote machine that makes `git status` slow, and after I closing the local machine(i.e. closing the communication), `git status` become fast again. But I cannot find a way to debug this.

My question is that if there exists some methods to debug this problem, or some answer that can solve it directly.

Comment: @phd Thanks for your detailed reply. I understand that running git over sshfs is slow. My question is that it should be fast when I ssh to the remote and work on it directly, but now it is fast only after I umount the repo on other machine.

Comment: @phd It might be confused. I actually has three machines. My laptop, a local machine and a remote machine. The problem is that run git on the remote directly is fast, but if I mount the remote in the local machine, running git on the remote directly become very slow. This is the point that I cannot firgure out why.

Comment: That's really strange. No idea, sorry. I doubt we can help. Try to run a packet dumper (`tcpdump`, `wireshark`) on port 22 to analyze traffic.

Comment: @phd I haven't thought of this method! Thanks and I will try it.